# Which systems can be considered balanced? How to predict a fair fight?

Tags: balance

I am just wondering which pen and paper systems could be considered rather "balanced" and which are not. The game and rules I know best is The Dark Eye - unfortunately I would consider it quite unbalanced:

- Creating characters with a wide variety of skills will always be weaker then a 
  character specialized in fighting only. This makes it hard to design a campaign: if 
  two characters are at level 5 it does not mean they are equally strong.
- It is almost impossible to guess your chances when rolling dice, you need a lot 
  experience or tools. This is bad because players cannot estimate reliably if they can
  trust their skills in critical situations. And GMs must worry about creating enemies
  which make up for a challenging fight.

This is why creating challenging fights seems problematic to me. If the enemies are strong I fear they become too strong and rather create weak ones. So my question is: Which systems support GMs in creating fair fights easily.

These are other systems I already own, and I want to test them in near future, but "so many games, so little time ..." ;)

- I am quite impressed by the [One Die System (1d6)](http://1w6.org/english) because its rules are 
  simple and you can calculate your chances easily. At the moment it is my favorite 
  in terms of balance and simplicity, but I still have to try it out. Also it is 
  a system only - so GMs need to create their own world or make a conversion
  of an existing system.
- Currently I read the new [Iron Kingdom RPG](http://privateerpress.com/iron-kingdoms) (2d6) core rules. It has a great
  setting and I read somewhere the rules are similar to the table top variants. I 
  hoped that due to this it would be a more "balanced" system. I love the possibilities
  in character creation, however you can create characters which rather focus on 
  socializing than fighting - this might cause a lack of tactical possibilities and
  I am yet too inexperienced to tell if it is a problem estimating the fairness of 
  a fight.
- Brand new [Splittermond](http://splittermond.de/) ('splinter moon', in German only). Will update if I 
  know more to its "fairness prediction".

How do you manage to create challenging but fair fights? Which other systems do you know and how do you classify them in terms of "creating a fair fight"?

Comment: Do you have any specific, quantitative or qualitative measurements for a fair fight? I'm sure we all have ideas as to what a fair fight is, but I'm also sure we differ on what "fair fight" really means...

Comment: I think this question would be improved if we restricted it to systems that made some particular *claim* of balance, so that we can evaluate if it lives  up to that claim. For many (probably most) systems, balance is not advertised or intended as a feature.

Comment: @KRyan Even then, it would be an unbounded list question. I don't think there's any way to de-forum this question and make it fit SE.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It could be formulated as a sys-rec question, if we got more details about *other* facets of the system that would be important. Though the question seems more about "how do you DM when balance isn't a thing?"

Comment: @KRyan I could see that being split off into a separate question, yeah. I'm dubious of saving the main "what systems are balanced" question since rarely does a general-interest question successfully transform into a one-best-answer game-rec—to write a good, narrow game-rec, the asker really needs to want only one and really put their heart in it.

Comment: To be clear, Vash, this isn't closed because it's not a good question, but simply because it doesn't fit this format: this site only works well with questions that have a one, single, "correct" answer, and that answer has to be something you can write reasonably concisely.

Comment: You might rethink the approach. Unfair fights are a very interesting thing. Have your not-so-combat characters use their other skills to overcome problems. You can design encounters in a way that allows the players braintime before they meet the enemy and turn the odds to their favor. Or they die. Even in DSA thats possible.

Answer (score 1):

The only System I know that offers more or less constant power level between different characters is [Rule of Cool's Legend](http://www.ruleofcool.com/). In fact the idea that, given two chars of the same level, their relative power must be the same is on the very core of the system.

On Legend, the rule is simple. A = A', where A and A' are two different characters with the same level. The whole system is extremely stable when you get the ways around it's rules.

Also, it's free.